# Kubernetes - Multiple pods per node vs one pod per node

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-pod

What is usually preferred in Kubernetes - having a one pod per node configuration, or multiple pods per node?

From a performance standpoint, what are the benefits of having multiple pods per node, if there is an overhead in having multiple pods living on the same node?

From a performance standpoint, wouldn't it be better to have a single pod per node?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is heavily dependent on your workload.

There are very specific scenarios (machine learning, big data, GPU intensive tasks) where you might have a one pod per node configuration due to an IO or hardware requirement for a singular pod. However, this is normally not a efficient use of resources and sort of eliminates a lot of the benefits of containerization.

The benefit of multiple pods per node is a more efficient use of all available resources. Generally speaking, managed kubernetes clusters will automatically schedule and manage the amount of pods that run on a node for you automatically, and many providers offer simple autoscaling solutions to ensure that you are always able to run all your workloads.

Comment: Can you please expand upon "However, this is normally not a efficient use of resources and sort of eliminates a lot of the benefits of containerization."?

You're suggesting that there are scenarios where having multiple pods is more efficient than having a single pod on a node. Can you name some of these scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

Running only a single pod per node has its cons as well. For example each node will need its own "support" pods such as metrics, logs, network agents and other system pods which most likely will not have its all resources
fully utilized. Which in terms of performance would mean that selecting the correct node size to pods amount ratio might result with less costs for the same performance as single pod per node.

On the contrary running too many pods in a massive node can cause lack of those resources and cause metrics or logs gaps or lost packets OOM errors etc.

Finally, when we also consider auto scaling, scaling up couple more pods on an existing nodes will be lot more responsive than scaling up a new node for each pod.

Comment: The autoscaling argument makes sense to me.

The supporting pods argument is still a bit hazy to me. Can you elaborate on it?

For example, let's say that 1 big pod can handle 1k QPS and 5 smaller pods can handle 200 QPS each. If the metrics/logs are a function of the QPS then in both scenarios wouldn't they be used at the same rate?